# Enable power view in SQL Server 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2012-express

i have installed SQL Server 2012 in my system, now i want to enable power view for reporting services. i don't know how to do this. can you tell me steps by step installation procedure...?

Answer (score 2):

[STEP BY STEP GUIDE INSTALLING SSRS 2012](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Instalating-and-Configuring-9a38de94)

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karang/archive/2012/04/13/step-by-step-guide-of-installing-power-view-with-powerpivot-2012.aspx